# Numpy: two dimensional arrays, delete the odd indexes and keep the same array format

Tags: python, numpy

My array looks like this:

```
a = ([1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[3,8])
```

I did the following to delete odd indexes :

```
a = [v for i, v in enumerate(a) if i % 2 == 0]
```

but it dives me now two different arrays instead of one two dimensional:

```
a= [array([1, 2]), array([4, 5])]
```

How can I keep the same format as the beginning? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy array indexing, not comprehensions:

```
c = a[list(range(0,len(a),2)),:]
```

If you define `c` as the output of a list comprehension, it will return a `list` of one-dimensional numpy arrays. Instead, using the proper indexing maintains the result a numpy array.

Note than instead of "deleting" the odd indices, what we do is specify what to keep: take all lines with an even index (the `list(range(0,len(a),2))` part) and for each line take all elements (the `:` part)

Answer (score 4):

That is as simple as

```
a[::2]
```

which yields the lines with even index.